# Twitter Typeahead and Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm having a bit of trouble implementing an idea I had to make twitter's typeahead suggestion property a little dynamic.

I have the following piece of code:

```
$(inputElement).typeahead({
        highlight: true,
        hint: false
    }, {
        name: 'engine',
        limit: 15,
        displayKey: config.displayKey,
        source: config.engine.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-suggestion-message">',
                    'No results matched your query.',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p> <span>{{name}}</span> - <span>{{email}}</span> - <span>{{phone}}</span> </p>'),
        }
    });
```

In the Handlebars.compile part, I'm printing the source's response keys, name, email and phone. What I want to do is, having set an object to hold some config:

```
var _setConfig = function (url, query, displaykey, suggestion) {
    config.url = url;
    config.query = query;
    config.displayKey = displaykey;
    config.suggestion = suggestion;
    console.log(config.suggestion);
};
```

I would like to change the suggestion part to:

```
suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p> <span>{{config.suggestion[0]}}</span> - <span>{{config.suggestion[1]}}</span> - <span>{{config.suggestion[2]}}</span> </p>')
```

Assuming I pass in an array (e,g ['name', 'email', 'phone']) as the suggestion parameter to the _setConfig() function.

Any ideas ??

Thanks :D

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Comment: @KevalPatel, Nop, I ended up with something. It always displays de name key, could not make it dynamic.